# C++ funtion template deduction of type from member type?

Tags: c++, template-argument-deduction, function-templates

I'm trying to write a C++ function template that, when called with an argument of a classes member alias, the function can deduce the class of that alias.  A *simplified* version of what would be nice:

```
class A {
  public :
    using x_t = float;
    void whatami() {printf("A\n");}
};

class B {
  public :
    using x_t = int;
    void whatami() {printf("B\n");}
};

template<typename T>
void fn(T::x_t x) {
  T t;
  t.whatami();
};

...
A::x_t a;
fn(a);
...
```

The g++ 7.3 error is:

```
play$ g++ --std=c++11 x.cpp
x.cpp:19:12: error: variable or field ‘fn’ declared void
 void fn(T::x_t x) {
            ^~~
x.cpp:19:16: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘x’
 void fn(T::x_t x) {
                ^
x.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
x.cpp:29:3: error: ‘fn’ was not declared in this scope
   fn(a);
   ^~
```

I'm interpreting this to mean that C++ can't deduce T as in `fn(T::x_t x)` but I'm not sure.

Thoughts?

Comment: Such a deduction is not possible. It would be very inefficient if allowed. The compiler would need to check every possible type for a `x_t` member and compare that against the function argument's type and what should happen if two classes match?. You might want to add *why* you need this function. There is probably a much simpler approach to this.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm gathering from your comment (and parktomatomi) that when the compiler sees ```fn(a)``` it doesn't actually know that a is A::x_t.  In that case I see why this becomes a problem.  As for the why?  It was an early attempt at something and turned into an intellectual challenge when I couldn't do it.  In the end, I'm doing something completely different. Thanks for all who responded.

Comment: Yes, after name-lookup, `A::x_t` and `float` are completely identical. `using` does not declare a new type. It simply provides an alias for the type. If you write `float a;` instead of `A::x_t a;` it is completely identical and the language does not provide any way of deciding whether `a` has been declared with `float` or `A::x_t` as type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't deduce `T` from `float`, which is what `a` is. It wont treat typedefs with any special consideration when trying to fill your template. It's also not going to search the whole type space for any type with a member by that name.

One way to get that deduction is to boost that member type with a reference to the owning class, and add an implicit conversion back to the primitive:

```cpp
template <typename TOwner, typename TData>
class x_t {
    TData data;
public:
    constexpr x_t() = default;
    constexpr x_t(TData data) : data(data) { }
    constexpr operator TData() const { return data; }
};

struct A {
    using x_t = x_t<A, float>;
    /*...*/
};
```

Then partial specialization will work correctly:

```cpp
template<typename TOwner, typename TData>
void fn(x_t<TOwner, TData> x) {
  TOwner t;
  t.whatami();
};
```

And you can use an instance in any type-safe function

```
A::x_t a(42.0);
std::cout << a; // 42.0
```

(sadly, `printf` doesn't count as type-safe. using streams here, `fmt::printf` from the excellent fmt library would also work).

It probably doesn't reach your goal of making it *easy* to deduce from a member, but it's a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

The below function should take the object(T) as you want to invoke the member function on it.

```
template<typename T>
void fn(T& x) 
{
  x.whatami();
};
```

The call for template function can be done as below:

```
A a;
fn(a);
```

It will print result as => A
Is this you want, right ?

Comment: I think you are circumventing the actual problem OP wants to solve. They seem to want to deduce the class containing the correct type alias. They don't know the class type they want to call on initially.

Answer (score 0):

Deducing from an arbitrary template id is like solving an arbitrary equation, which is far beyond the compiler’s capability. Think of this:

```
template <int N>
using S = std::integral_constant<int, /* a super complex radical involving 42nd powers and 84th roots */>;

template <int N>
constexpr int solve(S<N>)
{
    return N;
}
```

Do you think the compiler can `solve(std::integral_constant<int, 420>{});`? No.

In your case, the template id is limited to a finite number of cases, so a simple nonintrusive way to help the compiler is to solve the equation yourself:

```
template <typename x_t>
using solve = std::conditional_t<
    std::is_same_v<x_t, float>, A,
    std::conditional_t<
        // similar code for B
    >
>;
```